# How to filter one measure with filters applied to another table?

Tags: dax

I have a Measure Named "Sum of Projected Yields" (basically calculating the sum of Projected Yields) in a table called "Projected Yields".

I have another Measure Named "Sum of Harvested Yields" in a table called "Harvest Yields".

I want to subtract these measures( Sum of Harvested Yields - Sum of Projected Yields).

As these measures are not in the same table it is giving me wrong values after subtracting.

**Projected Yield:**

```
Fieldname  Projected Yield

1          2.90

2          2.99
```

**Harvest Yield:**

```
Fieldname  Harvest Yield

2           3.43

3           8.56
```

So when I filter on "Fieldname" the Measure "Sum of Harvested Yields" filters
for eg, when I filter on Fieldname = 2 , the Sum of Harvested Yields measure shows value 3.43

However the Measure "Sum of Projected Yields" does not filter, it shows the sum of both values(i.e 2.90 + 2.99).

I want it to show only for Fieldname = 2.

Comment: Do you have a relationship between the 2 tables in place?

Comment: No, these two tables don't have a direct relationship.
I have a dimension table "Filedname" and both have a relationship with the fieldname table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a dimension table, for `Fieldname` - you could use something like:

```
Dimension Table = 
GROUPBY ( 
    UNION ( 
        GROUPBY ( 'Projected Yield', 'Projected Yield'[Fieldname] ),
        GROUPBY ( 'Harvest Yield', 'Harvest Yield'[Fieldname] )
    ),
    [Fieldname]
)
```

Create a relationship between this Dimension table and both your fact tables, on `Fieldname`:

[image]

Now you can get accurate measures per Fieldname:

```
Surplus Yield = SUM ( 'Harvest Yield'[Harvest Yield] ) - SUM ( 'Projected Yield'[Projected Yield] )
```

See https://pwrbi.com/so_55593360/ for example PBIX file

Comment: Actually, I need to calculate this measure in the Harvest Yield Table,
and when I subtract these two measures, the Projected Yields are not being filtered by fieldname, it subtracts the total sum of Projected yield from every harvest yield

Comment: You can store the measure in any table you like - it makes no difference which table it's in. If you're trying to add it as a calculated column, then you'll need a different approach - but why would you add a column, when a measure does exactly what you want?

Comment: Hey, Thanks :)
I would like to calculate one more measure,
=Surplus Yield/Total Projected Yield
and calculating this gives wrong values as the Total Projected Yield gets filtered by Fieldname.

Comment: For eg, for Fieldname = 2,
Surplus Yield = 3.43-2.99
I would like to add one more measure,like
New Measure = Surplus Yield / Total Projected Yield
= 0.44/5.89
What I am getting is 0.44/2.99

Comment: Ask another question, rather than creeping scope in comments